# Add a XML element in the middle of the XML document

Tags: xml, powershell

I am writing PowerShell script to modify the XML file. I need to add a new element and add attributes to it. I tried using `CreateElement()` and `AppendChild()` methods but it doesnt help. Below is my sample input XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Subnet xmlns="http://google.com">
  <Id>Network_106</Id>
  <Name>Network_106</Name>
  <Description>
  </Description>
  <NetworkAddress>173.24.106.0</NetworkAddress>
  <NetworkMask>255.255.255.0</NetworkMask>
</Subnet>
```

I need to add the new elemetnt called `DeliveryServices` after a Description like below and add `Id` element inside it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Subnet xmlns="http://google.com">
  <Id>Network_106</Id>
  <Name>Network_106</Name>
  <Description>
  </Description>
<DeleveryServices>
  <Id>172.22.22.22</Id>
</DeleveryServices>
  <NetworkAddress>173.24.106.0</NetworkAddress>
  <NetworkMask>255.255.255.0</NetworkMask>
</Subnet>
```

I tried the below code, but it doesnt work.

```bsh
[xml]$xdoc = Get-Content "F:\Sample.xml"
$child = $xdoc.CreateElement("DeleveryServices")
$xdoc.Subnet.AppendChild($child)
$xdoc.Subnet.DeleveryServices.Id = "172.22.22.22"
```

I am getting this below error. And also `DeleveryServices` element is created at the end of the XML file. I want it after the description.

```
The property 'Id' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property
exists and can be set.
At line:44 char:17
+                 $xdoc.Subnet.DeleveryServices.Id = "172.22.22.22"
```

Comment: _"It doesn't work"_ is insufficient.  Explain what happens, show the actual output, and include any error messages.

Comment: @JimGarrison added error details.

Comment: I don't see a `<DeploymentServices>` node in the XML anywhere.  You cannot set an attribute on a non-existent node.

Comment: I need to create a new node called "DeliveryServices" .. Sorry my mistake.. edited the question@JimGarrison

Comment: Er, `Id` is an element, not a property, according to your posted example. Obviously you should create it just like that other element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a node `<DeleveryService>`, but that creates just an empty node. It doesn't magically create, add, or populate a child node `<Id>`. You need to do that yourself:

```
[xml]$xdoc = Get-Content "F:\Sample.xml"
$child = $xdoc.CreateElement("DeleveryServices")

$id = $xdoc.CreateElement("Id")
$id.InnerText = '172.22.22.22'
$child.AppendChild($id)

$xdoc.Subnet.AppendChild($child)
```

To add the new node after a particular other node you need to use `InsertAfter()` instead of `AppendChild()`, which obviously places the node at the end ("append").

```
$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($xdoc.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace('ns', $xdoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

$descr = $xdoc.SelectSingleNode('//ns:Description', $nsm)

$xdoc.Subnet.InsertAfter($child, $descr)
```

Beware that you need a namespace manager for selecting the `Description` node, because your XML data uses a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
$child = $xdoc.CreateElement("DeleveryServices")
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$xdoc.Subnet.AppendChild($child)
$xdoc.Subnet.DeliveryServices.Id = "172.22.22.22"
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that `DeleveryServices` != `DeliveryServices`

Comment: Its a typo. Still its not working. Showing same error.

Comment: How about `$child.Id = "172.22.22.22"`